# find select option by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Can anyone tell me why this works in older versions of jQuery (e.g. 1.4.2) but if you switch to a later version, e.g. (1.6 +) it stops working?

http://jsfiddle.net/nmvf6/1194/

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_button').click(function(){
        var unitName = "Unit2";
        $('.assUnit').find('option[text="'+unitName+'"]').remove();
    });

});
```

​

I have checked the error output in the console for the later versions, and an error seems to occur on the page load, before i've even got as far as it loading up my script and being able to click the button..

When I change the version to 1.8.0 for example and Run the page, [this error](https://postimg.cc/hfKwV35V) comes up in my Opera scripts console:

[image]

Which seems to be in a "mootools" file..but I didn't select mootools, i selected jQuery 1.8.0

:/

Thanks.

Comment: haha, you said 'assUnit'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using [`Attribute Equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector which selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value, option elements don't have `text` attributes, you can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector instead, try this:

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_button').click(function(){
        var unitName = "Unit2";
        $('.assUnit').find('option:contains('+unitName+')').remove();
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nmvf6/1198/)

If you want to select the element that has only certain value you can use the `filter` method:

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_button').click(function(){
        var unitName = "Unit2";
        $('.assUnit option').filter(function() {
             return $(this).text() === unitName
        }).remove();
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nmvf6/1207/)

Comment: Hi, see my comment on the other one who suggested contains

Comment: Hmm, just tried that but doesn't seem to work either. Not getting any console errors though. EDIT: got it working now, had to change "input" to "option" thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have more luck with this:

```
$('.assUnit').find('option:contains('+unitName+')').remove();
```

See also: [:contains() selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: Hi, contains isn't any good for this, as it has to be an exact match. contains('unit2') for example would also match 'unit200' and there will be a lot of select menus and options.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_button').click(function(){
       var unitName = "Unit2";
       $(".assUnit option:contains('"+unitName+"')").remove();
   });

});
```